# How to compile and run a C++ file?

Tags: major-mode, c++, c, ide, compile-mode

I don't know how to compile and run a C++ file in GNU Emacs. I searched on the various sites and stackexchange network, but from them what I understood was write something like `make compile`, and I don't know what does that mean, obviously compiling something. I even have looked at GNU Emacs reference card and Dired reference card on gnu.org, but I could not find a helpful code and explanation of how to compile and run a C++ file.

Can someone help me with compiling and running, how each is done separately, and what steps are? For example, I see `g++`, `gcc`, `-o`, `-Wall`, `foo.cpp`, `./.a` codes elsewhere but I don't know their function. Can someone explain their function, please? I have seen somebody's answer on stackoverflow which said:

> if something is on your `~/PATH`

What is that? How to put something in `~/PATH`.

I know I'm asking for too much, but I don't want to use ready-go IDEs or compilers, I want to use GNU Emacs, and I want to learn it hard way. Thanks.

PS: I use Linux Ubuntu 16.somenumber as an OS. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has very little to do with Emacs. Get a proper book on C++ that explains how to use a compiler, what the flags are for and why you'd want to write Makefiles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a lot of questions, but I will try to answer them in such a way that you can look up all the answers in detail.

Emacs is primarily a text editor; you will use it to edit your C++ files. Converting those files into a program that your computer can run is the job of a compiler. There are many C++ compilers, but you will want to use one called `gcc`. Emacs can invoke gcc for you, but it's generally more useful to have Emacs invoke a program called `make` instead. `make` is useful because it can take instructions from a `Makefile`, which is a file you create that contains instructions for building complicated programs. `make` also has an interesting set of built in rules (called "implicit rules" in the documentation) which allow it to compile simple programs without a Makefile at all.

For example, let's say that you create a file called test.cpp, with this code in it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

Save this file, and then type `M-x compile` to tell Emacs that you want to compile this file. Emacs will prompt you for the command to run, and the default is simply `make`. Type in `make test` and hit enter, and Emacs will run `make` with the argumment `test`. `make` will then run and look for your `test.cpp` file, and use `gcc` to compile it into an executable named `test`. You can then run that executable at the command line like any other command-line program.

Comment: @garakchy And after having compiled the first time you can use `recompile`, so I suggest you to bind a shortcut to recompile

Answer (score 0):

I accept the answer above as the real one. However, here is my own 2 satoshis(cents :) after looking for the internet about the answer. I learned that there are mainly 2 compilers for C++ which are GCC and G++. GCC is for C and G++ is for C++ mainly as far as I understand. I don't know if they come with the Linux Ubuntu inherently installed but when I tried to install them it was already installed in my machine. To install them you need to install `build-essentials` package in Ubuntu. They are included in that package. After that I tried to compile my C++ program again. I wrote `M-x compile` and GNU Emacs showed me `make -k` which is a default compile argument in my GNU Emacs. I was hitting Enter button, writing something extra as `g++ mycpp.cpp` etc after `make -k` but to no avail. Finally, I decided to remove `make -k` and write only `g++ mycpp.cpp` and voile it worked. It put its output to the `a.out` in the same folder. To get read the output all I needed to was `M-x shell` or `M-!` and then `./a.out` and it showed the output. I'm still open to the suggestions on how to edit default `make -k` or some other things so that instead of writing `g++ mycpp.cpp` I can just `make -k` it. I don't know, by the way, which one is a good practice for a programmer. I want to learn it. To the @wasamasa, look I learned something here but you voted my question to close. If it was closed I wouldn't have learned from suggestions here provided. I want to learn and improve myself. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I marked this question to be closed is because it's off-topic, meaning that this is the wrong place to learn about it. It would have been a different story if you asked about how to change the default command run by `M-x compile`. Feel free to open a new question for that specifically.